# MismatchedInputException while processing API request

Tags: java, api, jackson, shared-libraries, json-deserialization

I have an API defined in a RestController that takes in a json request. The pojo for the input is as below.

`class A{
    class List<SharedModel> sharedModels;
}`

and SharedModel looks like this.

`class SharedModel {
    DateTime datetime;
}`

Now in the curl call the json request payload is like this
`{[
   { "datetime" : "2020-01-16T22:50:47Z"}
]}`

I get a 400 bad request with the exception as below

`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of`org.joda.time.DateTime`(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2020-01-16T22:50:47Z')`

I cannot edit the SharedModel. Where and how do I write the deserializer for this?

Comment: How you are mapping the objects ?

Comment: All other fields are strings, so haven't had to define mappers yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install JavaTimeModule for ObjectMapper?